# Why does nvi think I have files being editing?

Tags: cron, freebsd, vi

I've got a couple of FreeBSD servers that throw several copies of the following error on reboot:

```
On Wed Oct 10 15:13:16 2012, the user root was editing a file named /tmp/crontab.s00huOAZD2 on the machine server, when it was saved for recovery. You can recover most, if not all, of the changes to this file using the -r option to vi:

    vi -r /tmp/crontab.s00huOAZD2
```

However, nobody was editing anything (at least not in recent memory).  I certainly don't want to recover whatever is in those files.  I've turned on clear_tmp (on boot) and cleaned out the tmp directory manually as well.  No change though, I get several copies of the above on every boot.  Even if I boot, then reboot immediately.  What's causing nvi to think I'm doing crontab editing and what's the best way to clean these out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the persistent temp directory `/var/tmp/` for a `Vi.recover` directory.